# How to Concat Parent tag with Child tag name in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

How to Concat Parent tag with Child tag name in XSLT

Currently I am able to get parent and child node values but i don't know how to join them as single value

```
<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>  //gives child name
<xsl:value-of select="name(..)"/> //gives parent name
```

I want to do something like `<xsl:value-of select="concat(name(..),name())"/>`

so result would be Parent_Child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple options:

- [`concat()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-concat)
- Multiple `value-of`, like

  `<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>_<xsl:value-of select="name(..)"/>`

Comment: Thanks. How can i get parent of next level like name(...) ?. But ... is not working

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you looking for `../..`? Or the [`ancestor-or-self::*`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#axes) axis?

Comment: `concat()` function is in the question. What this answer is missing is an example. That would be `concat(name(..),'-',name())`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new element name based on that

```
<xsl:element name="{concat(name(..),'_',name(.))}"/>
```